# \underbrace error

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm trying to write an equation, but I keep getting an "Undined control sequence error on the line my equation is one, and I can't seem to figure out what the error is. Can any of you guys seen an errors in the equation?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$
\theta^* = \bf{argmin}\underbrace{{1\over2}(g-F(\theta))^T(g-F(\theta))}_\text{f(\theta)}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably have `\text` marked as undefined; you need `\usepackage{amsmath}`, for it. By the way, `\bf{argmin}` is *wrong*: use `\mathbf{argmin}` or, better yet, `\operatorname{\mathbf{argmin}}`. However, `\text` is wrong in that context: just `_{f(\theta)}` should be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) package for the text command. And then you should use `\mathbf{}` for the boldface math and `\textbf{}` for text. `\bf,\it` etc. is obsolete. [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

Then `\text{}` is used for non-math content but `\theta` needs math mode.

So overall the following works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\theta^* = \mathbf{argmin}\underbrace{{1\over2}(g-F(\theta))^T(g-F(\theta))}_{\text{f}(\theta)}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still not convinced that the "f" should be upright. Also `\operatorname{\mathbf{argmin}}` is more correct and `\over` should be changed into `\frac` or perhaps `\dfrac`.

Comment: @egreg Indeed I didn't pay too much attention to the content but rather trying to replicate the problem. So I just tried to make it work.